# Angular 2 show current formatted date

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following code to show the current date:

```
this.whatTime = Observable.interval(1000).map(x => new Date()).share();
```

And in my template:

```
{{whatTime | async}}
```

My problem is that the date is too long and not formatted as I wish.

[image]

All I want to show is: 15/09/16 19:07:11

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Angular's built-in `DatePipe`:

```
{{ whatTime | async | date:'d/M/yy hh:mm:ss' }}
```

This converts `Thu Sep 15 2016 18:15:17 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)` into your desired template: `15/9/16 06:15:17`.

You can read more about Angular's `DatePipe` and its formats [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html) and you can read more about Angular's pipes in general [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use Angular2 built in Date Pipe

```
{{whatTime | async | date:'yMdjm'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Then you should call it like that:

```
moment(timestamp).fromNow();
```

This will give you the current time.

Comment: No moment.js tag and there is functionality in Angular (which is tagged) to do the job.