# Get time from "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss" in angular 2

Tags: json, angular, datetime-format

Need  to bind time  from the format "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss" . But  some  minutes  are  not  binding  correctly. used foloowing  fomatting  technique.

```
    {{myDateTime| date:"HH:mm" }}
```

Example 1:
myDateTime - "1900-01-01T08:00:00"
viewed as    - "07:49"
Need as    - "08:00"

Example 2:
myDateTime - "1900-01-01T23:00:00"
viewed as    -  "22:49"
Need as    - "23:00"

Comment: I see no problem with that, here is a plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/VvM1neeDgG2IcPVc8irp?p=preview

Comment: I had such issue. The problem was the javascript was taking time provided by API as a UTC time. The conversion was done onto that at server side and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45330707/495157) on this. The formatting codes are specifically listed [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.1/packages/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts#L16-L143). That should be a 24hr clock with seconds having leading zero if under 10 seconds. So looks ok to me. Your dates have century of 1900. That looked odd btw. But  `this.myDateTime = new Date(1900, 0, 1, 8, 0);` outputs good time for me too in the plunker.