# Angular Typescript - converting string to date for comparison

Tags: angular, typescript

If I have 2 strings in Typescript containing dates in this format

"17 October 2018 10:05 AM"

How can I convert them to Date types so I can compare them?

I had tried `new Date(stringDate1)` and `moment(stringDate1)` but they result in invalid dates obviously.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/. But I really wonder why you have dates in such a format in the first place. Where does that string come from? Why doesn't this source use the ISO format?

Comment: just what I need, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45330707/495157 https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: Be aware, adding moment.js in Angular adds a ton of weight to your application. If all you need to do is create a Date object from this string, I would consider simply breaking the string apart and creating the date object that way.