# Bind date to a formControlname input in Angular7

Tags: angular, angular7

I am new to angular. I have an input with type `date`. How will I bind the date to this input?

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="startDateInput">
```

i tried the following but it didn't work:

```
this.createForm.patchValue({
    startDateInput:this.resourceData['period'].start,
});
```

please help to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330319/angular2-setting-date-field-on-reactive-form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - Setting date field on reactive form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330319/angular2-setting-date-field-on-reactive-form)

Answer (score 1):

For date type input you need to convert the date

```
this.createForm.patchValue({ 
    startDateInput: (new Date()).toISOString().substring(0,10), 
});
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tj7byh?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follow

```
const date = new Date();
this.createForm.controls['startDateInput'].setValue(date)
```